# Does VM share resources (CPU cores/memory) with its host machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

In my VMWare player/Virtualbox only has one VM. if I allocated 8 processors to this VM but it only use 2 processors when running, are the other 6 processors free to be used by the host? Or the 8 processors are reserved for the VM only?
How about the RAM? Will VM release the unused memory to the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware does not allocate actual physical cores to the VM. It will *utilize* the number of cores specified, but those same cores will continue to be used by the host as well.